# Name for instruments that can only play one octave, vs one that can play many octaves?

Tags: terminology, instruments, octave, instrument-range

**Is there a word for instruments that are limited to only one octave, as opposed to instruments that can play multiple octaves?** I think this is a matter of classifying instruments with a certain narrow [musical range](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_%28music%29), regardless of where that range is on the spectrum of pitches.

Less than 1 octave:
[Berimbau](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berimbau), simple 4-hole flutes, various drums and other instruments that have a very limited range.

More than 1 octave:
Piano, guitar, human whistling or singing.

---

I found [polyphony & monophony](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyphony_and_monophony_in_instruments) but that is about more than one note at once, not multiple octaves - for example, I can whistle in many octaves but can only whistle one note at a time.

Comment: I don't think there's a name for this.  But I want to point out that all flutes should be able to overblow and produce overtones, and half-holing can produce more notes than the number of finger holes would seem to indicate.

Comment: "Limited range" and "single-/multi-octave" should be sufficient.

Comment: if you hum while you whistle you can create a neat "tractor beam" effect popularized by Jim Carrey.  Just a side note on the whistlin' and polyphony

Comment: Perhaps 'tonal' vs 'atonal' is what I'm looking for

Comment: @cr0 I don't think so. Those don't have anything to do with range.

Answer (score 3):

in botany, a plant that fruits many times vs one that fruits only once is called Polycarpic vs Monocarpic.. So maybe Poly-octave and mono-octave?

Comment: That was my first thought too. Polyphonic and Monophonic are musical terms too. Poly-octave, Mono-octave makes a lot of sense to me.

Answer (score 2):

There is no specific English term that reflects this distinction.  You're going to have to use a multi-word construction, like M. Read's multi-octave vs. single-octave, or introduce and define a custom term yourself.